# Remove key from all objects in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have the following array of objects:

```
[{id:1, value:"100", name:"dog" ...},
{id:2, value:"200", name:"cat" ...},
{id:3, value:"300", name:"fish"....},
{id:4, value:"400", name:"mouse" ...},
{id:5, value:"500", name:"snake"...}]
```

I want to filter the object array and keep only two keys, `id` and `value` to get something like this:

```
[{id:1, value:"100"},
{id:2, value:"200"},
{id:3, value:"300"},
{id:4, value:"400"},
{id:5, value:"500"}]
```

Currently, I'm traversing through the object array with a for loop and doing a `push()` to an empty array with the new variables. Is there an easier way to do this?

I wanted to use Lodash like `_.pluck(PetList, 'id', 'value');` but lodash extracts the value only, not the key.

Comment: it's more mapping than filtering ...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`Array#filter` filters individual items out of the array, not certain keys from an object in the array. You could use the method [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform the objects and only keeping the keys you want. `map` is designed to transform each element of an array to something new, "mapping" the old value to a new value:

```
let newPetList = PetList.map(pet => ({ 
    id: pet.id,
    value: pet.value
}));
```

The above traverses the array, and stores the current object in `pet`. It then returns a new object from an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which will be the corresponding transformed object in `newPetList` with only keys `id` and `value` from `pet`. The result is that all objects in the old array are mapped to a new object with no `name` key.

You could also, with object destructuring, filter put unwanted properties like so:

```
let newPetList = petList.map(({ name, ...rest }) => rest);
```

This binds the `name` property to `name` and keeps the rest in `rest`, which you can return to remove the `name` key.

Answer (score 5):

What you are trying to achieve is called mapping rather filtering. Here's a solution

```js
var array = [{id:1, value:"100", name:"dog"},
{id:2, value:"200", name:"cat"},
{id:3, value:"300", name:"fish"},
{id:4, value:"400", name:"mouse"},
{id:5, value:"500", name:"snake"}];
var result = array.map(function(obj) {
    return {id: obj.id, value: obj.value};
});

console.log(result);
```